# Prometheus DB get Api call, how can I get data for last 15 mins?

Tags: node.js, prometheus

Prometheus DB get Api call, how can I get data for las 15 mins?

I can get data for name end instance

```
for example
query=netdata_redis_bgsave_health_status_average{instance='ny-r-user2'}
```

but how can I get for range or last mins data

```
query=up&start=2018-11-23T09:10:30.781Z&end=2015-11-23T09:12:00.781Z&step=15s'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line return .json don for last 15 min, step 10 seconds

http:/localhost:9090/api/query?query=**name**[15m]